# I am trying to create a RecyclerView in Kotlin but having what seems a simple issue

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

So im trying to create a RecyclerView but im getting errors on "class RecyclerAdapter" and "override fun onBindViewHolder" Reference photo down below
[image: Errors]

On the first it states **"Class 'RecyclerAdapter' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int): Unit defined in androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter"**

The second error states "**onBindViewHolder' overrides nothing**"

im am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ai9rSGcDhyQ&ab_channel=CodePalace Here the snippet from the tutorial that Im having problems with
[image: Heres the snippet of the video]

I copied the tutorial almost word for word but I have no idea why im still getting these erros and trust me I have tried researching here and elsewhere including android documentation for solutions but to no avail. Here is what I tried to try to fix it:When I added ***RecyclerView.Viewholder*** both errors disappear but then the variables become unresolved

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemTitle.text=titles[position]
    holder.itemDetail.text=details[position]
    holder.itemPicture.setImageResource(images[position])


}
```

[image]
I would be very grateful if you can find a solution to this issue.

thank you

```
class RecyclerAdapter (private var titles:List<String>,private var details: List<String>,private var 
         images:List<Int>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){


       inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val itemTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
    val itemDetail:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.description)
    val itemPicture: ImageView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image)

    init {
        // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
        itemView.setOnClickListener{v:View->
            val position:Int =adapterPosition
            Toast.makeText(itemView.context," You clicked on item # 
          ${position+1}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    val v =LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(v)

}



override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemTitle.text=titles[position]
    holder.itemDetail.text=details[position]
    holder.itemPicture.setImageResource(images[position])
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return titles.size

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder`, not `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

```
class RecyclerAdapter (private var titles:List<String>,private var details: List<String>,private var 
         images:List<Int>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>()
```

Comment: Ok that worked I dont why I didnt notice that maybe its because it was really late lol